# Problem with initial rows selecte, react table v8

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table-v8

my mind is almost expoilt, can´t make a initial state of rows selection with table react table. Try to put initial state by "rowSelection", works fine when i put a string like this: [true, false, true, false]. But when i'm trying to get asyncronily this data it doesn´t work, and first value taken when render is a enmpy string for "initialSelectedRowIds()", because el estado "data" is too a empy string at first render.
How can i make it corretly??, please help me.

```
import * as React from 'react'

import {
  useState,
  useReducer,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  useEffect,
  useContext
} from 'react'

import {
  Column,
  ColumnDef,
  createColumnHelper,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  Table,
  useReactTable,
} from '@tanstack/react-table'


import {AdminContext} from "../context/AdminContext.js";
import AppContext from "../context/AppContext";
import "../styles/ModalUsersSector.scss"

function TableManyToMany(props){
  const [token] = useContext(AdminContext);
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const rerender = useReducer(() => ({}), {})[1]

  /* API connector to get data users of sector*/
  useEffect(() => {
    const makeData = async () => {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
      };
    
      const response = await fetch(`/api/sector_users/${props.id}`, requestOptions);
      if(!response.ok){
        console.log('error')
      }else{
        const users = await response.json();
        setData(users)
      }
    }
    makeData()
  }, [])

  // Make columns
  const columns = useMemo(() => [
    {
      id: 'select',
        header: ({ table }) => (
          <IndeterminateCheckbox
            {...{
              checked: table.getIsAllRowsSelected(),
              indeterminate: table.getIsSomeRowsSelected(),
              onChange: table.getToggleAllRowsSelectedHandler(),
            }}
          />
        ),
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className="px-1">
            <IndeterminateCheckbox
              {...{
                checked: row.getIsSelected(),
                disabled: !row.getCanSelect(),
                indeterminate: row.getIsSomeSelected(),
                onChange: row.getToggleSelectedHandler(),
              }}
            />
          </div>
        ),
    },
    {
      accessorKey: 'users_name',
      header: 'Nombre',
      footer: props => props.column.id,
    },
    {
      accessorKey: 'users_role',
      header: 'Puesto',
      footer: props => props.column.id,
    },
    {
      accessorKey: 'users_department',
      header: 'Centro',
      footer: props => props.column.id,
    },
    {
      accessorKey: 'users_center',
      header: 'Gerencia',
      footer: props => props.column.id,
    },
  ], [])

  //Make Checkbox
  function IndeterminateCheckbox({
  indeterminate,
  className = '',
  ...rest
  }) {
    const ref = useRef()
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (typeof indeterminate === 'boolean') {
        ref.current.indeterminate = !rest.checked && indeterminate
      }
    }, [ref, indeterminate])

    return (
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        ref={ref}
        className={className + ' cursor-pointer'}
        {...rest}
      />
    )
  }


  /* For get initial selected users for the sector*/
  const initialSelectedRowIds = () => {
    let initialList=[]

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let user = data[i];
      let matchingSector = user.sectors.some(sector => sector.id === props.id);

      if (matchingSector) {
        initialList.push(true)
      }else{
        initialList.push(false)
      }
    }
    return initialList
    
  }

  //Make table
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    initialState: {
      rowSelection: initialSelectedRowIds(),
    }
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="styled-table-user" >
        <thead>
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map(headerGroup => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(header => (
                <th key={header.id}>
                  {header.isPlaceholder
                    ? null
                    : flexRender(
                        header.column.columnDef.header,
                        header.getContext()
                      )}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows.map(row => (
            <tr key={row.id}>
              {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => (
                <td key={cell.id}>
                  {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
  )
}

export default TableManyToMany
```

One more thing, the data is rendering fine in table. I whondering why "data" is empy when i'm trying put initial rows selected. I tried to use useMemo for put initial rows selected, it didn't work too.